# How to Use Reduce function in JS

Tags: javascript

I have the following data in globalAskData array
and mid price is 99328 and range of 500 so last value should be less than 99328 + 500 => 99828

99320, 99328, 99332, 99344

.

.

99432, 99455, 99464

.

.

99821, 99823, 99844

and expect output should be

99332, 99344, 99432
.
.
.
99823

Here is what I tried:

```
globalAskData = tempDataAsk.reduce(function(ask) {
                    if (ask.price < (mid_price + 500) && ask.price > mid_price) {
                        return ask;
                    }
                }, tempDataAsk[0])
```

Comment: where do you define mid price

Comment: Although it is abused regularly, `.reduce()` is about turning an array into a single value. A common example would be adding all elements to together: `.reduce((a, c) => a + c, 0)`; if you want to remove values from your array, you're looking for [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a `filter` instead of `reduce`.

Something like this:

```
globalAskData = tempDataAsk.filter(function(ask) {
                    return ask.price < (mid_price + 500) && ask.price > mid_price;
                })
```